# Ejecutar msiexec sin mostrar

Tags: cmd, batch

Quiero ejecutar un paquete `msi` desde un archivo `.cmd`, pero tengo 2 inconvenientes:

- Mediante este código me permite instalar el paquete `msi`, pero me sale la ventana donde me pide presionar el botón siguiente y `finish`, ademas me pide si quiero ejecutar como administrador

  ```
  msiexec /i "C:\pruebainstall\setup2.msi"
  ```
- Luego ejecuto el siguiente código para instalar el paquete `msi` como administrador.

  ```
  msiexec /a "C:\pruebainstall\setup2.msi"
  ```

Y con esto igual me muestra el asistente de instalación y ya no me pide que ejecute como administrador, pero el problema es que me sale un mensaje que indica que el instalador no tiene privilegios de administrador y no me permite instalar.

Agradecería si me podrían ayudar con este código de tal manera que al ejecutar el archivo `.cmd` me pueda instalar sin mostrar el asistente de instalación y que no me solicite permisos de instalador.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar:

```
msiexec /i /a c:\path\to\package.msi /quiet /qn /norestart
```

se le dice instalación silenciosa.

esto solo funcionara si abriste el CMD como administrador

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, aplico el mismo codigo y cuando ejecuto solo se muestra la ventana de cmd y se cierra pero no me instala nada. Saludos

Comment: tienes privilegios de administrador?

Comment: actualice el post

Comment: como te termino de ir??

Comment: Me funciono bien, no ejecutaba en una maquina virtual pero en mi pc local si logro funcionar. Gracias

Comment: @Freddy a que bien escoje una respuesta la que se haya acerado mas a tu pregunta. saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar como administrador, usa el comando `runas`<sup>1</sup> como prefijo antes de realizar la tarea en el archivo `.cmd` que tienes:

```
runas /user:Administrator
```

O `/user:Administrador` dependiendo de si tu versión esta en español o ingles *(Creo que no tiene que ver)*.

En la misma linea agregas el comando a ejecutar entre comillas *(Tomado de la respuesta de [Francisco Núñez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81267/4499))*

```
"msiexec /i c:\path\to\package.msi /quiet /qn /norestart"
```

El contenido de tu archivo `.cmd` ahora debería ser algo como esto:

```
runas /user:Administrator "msiexec /i c:\path\to\package.msi /quiet /qn /norestart"
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente, te dejo esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5944180/5622844) en SO relacionada.

<sup>1</sup>: Para utilizar el comando, necesitas tener la cuenta de administrador activada y tener una version superior a Windows 2000 *(Segun [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas))*.